# Unknown error during fedora 24 mate initial update

Tags: linux, fedora, grub, updates, dnf

i ran the proper dnf update command but in the middle of cleanup i got logged out and some of my processes got restarted. on restart nothing new was installed including the new kernel. now dnf won't recognize the missing update packages, it keeps saying that the system is up to date but it isn't. i even tried dnf clean all and that did nothing any help would be greatly appreciated because i would prefer not to reload my computer
i literally just loaded it
on a side note before the update i edited grub.cfg to remove nomodset from my kernel params, but i don't see how that would affect it

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is reinstall the packages that were trying to be installed during the update. 
To get the list of packages use the command

```
sudo dnf history
```

That will provide a transaction list in order of most recent first, along with a transaction number. Using the latest transaction number use the command

```
sudo dnf history info NUMBER
```

To get a list of packages involved in that transaction. Its possible the update wasnt the most recent transaction, so repeat until you find the right one.

Depending on your shell skills, the next part might be a bit tedious. You need to compile a list of the packages to provide as an argument to dnf. If its a small list you can copy and paste them. If its a long list, I would suggest putting them in a text file. You can separate the packages by a space or a new line.

The command you will use once the list is compiled is

```
sudo dnf reinstall PKGLST
```

Where PKGLST is either the actual package names (copy and paste with each pkg name separated by a space) or if you have them in a file, assuming the path and file name of /home/purpe/pkg.lst use this syntax:

```
sudo dnf reinstall $(cat /home/purpe/pkg.lst)
```

This will force a reinstall of all of them regardless of their current state.

If you have issues make sure the list of packages is accurate - no missing spaces, no extra info from dnf history, no typos. 
Experience tells me that's where things nearly always go wrong.

If you can't address the issue, post the dnf output and the commands you tried. Use something like pastebin because the pkg list and dnf output will likely be long

Comment: Thanks for the tip. For what it's worth I tried dnf update kernel* but it said there was nothing to update, but I will try your suggestion and keep you posted.

Comment: The reinstall command doesn't verify that the package is installed but only that it (dnf) thinks it is, so it should work where install and update will not.

Comment: i did what you told me to but i got this output: pastebin.com/YfwxVtSQ then it failed both times. i am truly at a loss.

Comment: In the list of packages, you'll have to strip off the version info off the file names. For example libreport-fedora-2.7.1-1.fc24.x86_64  should be libreport-fedora. Just to verify that that will work ok, you can test reinstalling one or two packages by themselves before updating the whole list; just call it with only a single package name like sudo dnf reinstall libreport-fedora  .  If that works, then update the file list by stripping off the version and arch info. To verify that your list is using package names recognized by dnf, replace the reinstall command with search.

Comment: I don't recommend the --allow-erasing as it could cause some serious issues. Not that you don't have one already, but it could be worse. As I said, getting the package list correct is nearly always the issue with doing this.

Comment: I did as you suggested and it didn't work. here are my findings: [pastebin.com/ALSLUyHd] at this point it might make more sense to just reload my laptop and hope this doesn't repeat its self.

Comment: I did not use that option each time. I have decided to reload in hope that that will fix my problom

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43980/discussion-between-purpe-fedora-and-argonauts).

Comment: I am closing this topic now due to giving up after the same problem  reoccurring even after a reinstall using the same methods. I plan to reinstall fedora with kde instead because I have not ran into this problem with it. I will chalk it up to a bug in that particular ISO file. Thanks for your time and effort to help but I'm labeling it as unfixable.

Comment: Ouch. Sorry about that.

Comment: That's alright it's not your fault thanks for your understanding